# Update Question: How to Mock MapToJson Class

Tags: spring-boot, junit

this is an update to my previous question.  I have a Utility class which I already manage to cover with my unit test except when the condition returns false.

Here is my class:

```java
@Component
public class Utils {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    public <E> String mapToJsonString(E object) {
        try {
            if (object == null) {
                throw new IOException(ErrorMessage.ERROR_PROCESSING_JSON_NULL);
            }else {
                return mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(object); //NullPointer Here
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            loggingService.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "1", ErrorMessage.ERROR_MAPPING_TO_JSONSTRING, e);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my unit test

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ATMMonitoringApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class ObjectToJsonStringTest {

    @SpyBean
    private ATM atm;

    @Autowired
    private Utils utils;

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        myModelClass = new MyModelclass();
            myModelClass.setStatus("U");
            myModelClass.setTermCode("001");
            myModelClass.setLocation("BGC");
    }

    @Test
    public void testObjectToJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String output = utils.mapToJsonStringmyModelClass 
        assertNotNull(output);
    }

    @Test
    public void testObjectToJsonNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String output = utils.mapToJsonString(null);
        assertNull(output);
    }

    @Test
    public void testJsonParsingException() {
        myModelClass = new MyModelclass();
            myModelClass = null;
        String output = utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass); 
        Mockito.when(loggingService.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "1", ErrorMessage.ERROR_MAPPING_TO_JSONSTRING, new Exception()))
        .thenReturn("");
        assertThat(output).isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Stack trace says that i have a null pointer on this line of code:

```
return mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(object);
```

Please help me on this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  I just change this

```
@Mock
private ObjectMapper mapper;
```

From @MockBean and it covered the whole class.